# Serverless framework CLI vs GUI. Eg. AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Why would anyone use Serverless framework CLI to write the lambda functions or deploy them when we have AWS console GUI? Are there any specific benefits out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you don't develop and deploy a lambda function in isolation, instead it is one part of your cloud infrastructure. That can include other lambdas, S3 buckets, databases, API Gateways, IAM roles, environment variables and much more.

Serverless framework is allows you to write your infrastructure as code. For AWS services, it translates `serverless.yaml` config files into AWS cloudformation files, and from there deploys any new or updated services you define. You lambda function is just one part of that.

A major benefit of writing and deploying this way is that you can use your favourite editor locally, and can check your code into version control (i.e. git). This is not just for your lambda code, but also your infrastructure config i.e. `serverless.yaml` and associated files.

Comment: This makes lot of sense to me. Thanks for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The Serverless Framework is more than just a replacement for the AWS Console (GUI). You can definitely set everything up via the AWS console for a Serverless application but how do you share that with your team? What if you wish to deploy that repeatedly into multiple applications? The Serverless Framework gives you a configuration file, usually called serverless.yml, where you define all the services within AWS (and other vendors, there is support for more than just AWS) and then you use the CLI to perform functions on this configuration file such as deploy, invoke and lot more.

Then there are the Serverless Framework plugins designed by the community around the project to make other tasks even easier such as unit testing, configuration of S3 buckets, CloudFront and domains to make frontend deployment easier and a lot, lot more.

Lastly, but most importantly, there is a professional product provided in addition to the open source framework that you can use to add on monitoring, deployment management, troubleshooting, optimisation, CI/CD and too many other benefits to list here.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, if you are doing a big project the Serverless framework has a lot of benefits, imagine you developing an MVC c# project with notepad. How do you feel about that? 
The framework are done to make our life ( for developers ) very much easier.